# finding duplicates with Join & Where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which looks for student records matched by a given criteria (same ClassNum AND matching names or matching emails).  Any student with a status of 'Deleted' should be ignored.

The following query finds the proper duplicates and ignores deleted students in 'Students', but I cannot find a way to prevent it matching a deleted student in 'dup'.

Case 1: There are two "John Smith" registered for the same class.  The query will return 2 rows, one for each John Smith found.  This is proper behavior.

Case 2: There are two "John Smith" registered for the same class, but one has the status of 'Deleted'.  The query returns one row of the non-deleted John Smith.  This is not what I want.

I've tried placing the two WHERE clauses inside the ON section, separating the clauses between ON and WHERE, etc., but all give the same result.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Students.Id,
                    Students.ClassNum,
                    Students.Lastname,
                    Students.Firstname,
                    Students.Status,
                    Students.Email
               FROM Students
         INNER JOIN (
                      SELECT Id,ClassNum,Email,Lastname,Firstname,Status 
                        FROM Students
                    ) dup
                 ON (    Students.Id != dup.Id 
                     AND Students.ClassNum = dup.ClassNum 
                     AND (   (    Students.Email = dup.Email 
                              AND Students.Email != ''
                             )
                          OR (    Students.Lastname = dup.Lastname 
                              AND Students.Firstname = dup.Firstname)
                         )
                     )
               WHERE Students.Status != 'Deleted' 
                 AND dup.Status != 'Deleted'
```

Comment: Your query should not be resulting in "Case 2".  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with the data you are using?

Comment: The real case is much more complicated, so let me see if I can pare it down for SQL Fiddle.  It will take a while.

Comment: I agree with Gordon that Case 2 should not be bringing up the one non-deleted student (assuming there is only 1 pair of dupes: 1 student deleted, 1 student not deleted).  Fiddle here to prove it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9a1c/5.  If it were bringing up one non-deleted record, I would think it was performing as expected.  If you were looking for non-deleted students from both tables, you could do this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9a1c/7

Answer (score 0):

A Logical **OR** usually means a SQL UNION; so try this instead:

```
SELECT Students.Id,
       Students.ClassNum,
       Students.Lastname,
       Students.Firstname,
       Students.Status,
       Students.Email
  FROM Students lhs
  JOIN Students rhs
     on lhs.ClassNum  = rhs.ClassNum
    and lhs.Firstname = rhs.Firstname
    and lhs.LastName  = rhs.LastName
    and lhs.Status   != 'DELETED'
    and rhs.Status   != 'DELETED'
UNION
SELECT Students.Id,
       Students.ClassNum,
       Students.Lastname,
       Students.Firstname,
       Students.Status,
       Students.Email
  FROM Students lhs
  JOIN Students rhs
     on lhs.ClassNum  = rhs.ClassNum
    and lhs.Email     = rhs.Email
    and lhs.Status   != 'DELETED'
    and rhs.Status   != 'DELETED'
```

Comment: Does not work.  Tried taking out all "OR" and just matching on email, but the same results.